# Why all expressions on Workflow Foundation 4.0 are Visual Basic syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, vba, expression, workflow-foundation-4

In `Workflow Foundation 4.0` (even older versions ), all expressions are `Visual Basic` syntax even I choose though the `C#` project?

Why these expressions are not C# syntax?

Comment: Why down vote and close vote? Dear commenters and voters please leave a comment :)

Comment: perhaps because you are asking for speculation as to why a company has chosen to do things. from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face

Comment: I don't as 'company has chosen to do things'. I ask why different syntax using in another language. That's different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real reason was that Visual Basic was the only language that provided an in-memory compiler.  For C# expressions we had to take a different approach.

Comment: This applies to .NET 4 only. C# support added in .NET 4.5

Comment: F# has this from .net 3.5 (from the beginning of F#) :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, it is due to all programming syntax in office and other vba. Workflow foundation has interface to create workflow in designer application by not programmers. As ms excel, ms access and so on.

Comment: VB is closer to natural English language, which C# is not (uses more symbols)

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way it is in the older versions. If you can work with 4.5, C# expressions have been implemented for C# Workflow projects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781025.aspx